# EthersJS JSON to sha256: Error string too long

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, ethers.js

what I'm trying to accomplish is creating a hash of a JSON object. This will then be used as a bytes32 parameter when minting a token.

I thought the best way to go about this is to first stringify a javascript object using `JSON.stringify` Then format it to bytes32 using `ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(JSON.stringify)` then taking that and putting it into `ethers.utils.sha256(bytes32String)` However, I get halted at `ethers.utiles.formatBytes32String` with the error message `bytes32 string must be less than 32 bytes` which makes sense. So instead of using `ethers.utils.formatBytes32String` I instead directly pass the stringified JSON into `sha256` which then results in the error message `Error: invalid arrayify value` which also makes sense because sha256 takes in bytes32.

So now I'm a bit stuck, I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using `ethers.utils.id(JSON.stringify)`. Though I'd like to know how to do this manually without using the `id` function if anyone has any insights on this.

Comment: Take a look at the [`utils.id` documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-id). It calculates the keccak256 of the string. The error causes by sha256 probably is because it expect an array and not a text, you could have used Buffer.from() to build the array from the text.